# A new user titled "other" has suddenly appeared on my login

Tags: login, login-items

I have tried to disable root user but when I get to the edit menu in the Directory Utility the option showing is "Enable Root User" so I'm guessing it's currently disabled.
I also have the enabled the guest user but this has not fixed the issue.
I can log in to the "other" user using my admin name and pw.
I haven't installed any new applications.
Concerned it's a security/hacking issue.
I don't have much tech skills.
I would appreciate any help - thanks

Comment: root is disabled by default - how did you enable it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm saying I think the root user is disabled.

Comment: I boot from an external HD as my internal HD is corrupted. I accidentally removed the usb lead I usually connect the external drive to. Could that have triggered this?

Comment: If you logged in with your admin name and password entering them in two fields then you logged in as that admin user.

Comment: What is the actual issue?

Comment: I just want to know why the "other" user has suddenly appeared on my login screen. Has anything sinister happened? Like someone/hacker remotely done this?